# UWP FindName return null

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an UWP app with a MainPage containing a SplitView called Splitview :

```
<SplitView x:Name="SplitView" ...>
```

In this SplitView, i have a usercontrol containing a ListView for navigation, when a ListViewItem is clicked, i navigate to another page but i want to close SplitView's pane before navigate. So in my usercontrol code behind in ListeView itemclick event i access parent frame and then trying to use FindName for access SplitView and close it :

```
var parentPage = ((Frame)Window.Current.Content);
if (parentPage != null)
{
    SplitView splitview = (SplitView)parentPage.FindName("SplitView");
    splitview.IsPaneOpen = false;
}
```

parentPage have a nice reference to MainPage, but this line :

```
SplitView splitview = (SplitView)parentPage.FindName("SplitView");
```

always return null. Would I have missed Something ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards

Comment: I'm a little confused, why is `parentPage` of type `Frame` when the variable name implies a `Page`? Which is it, `Frame` or `Page`?

Comment: It was my error indeed : it was a Frame and i should use it as a Page. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Frame` is an object with navigation history, backstack etc. An application's window has one content element which normally is the Frame as you mentioned. But the Frame itself has a content element as well, which is the current `Page` (or `FrameworkElement` in general) shown in this Frame. So to get your `currentPage` you need to do the following:

```
var parentPage = (Page)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content;
```

Answer (score 3):

`FindName` is only returning the element from a direct child of the current control. It is not recursively going through all descendants to find a match.

When debugging this kind of issues, you can use the "Live Visual Tree" allowing you to easily find how the XAML controls are organized:

[image: live visual tree]

Since your `SplitView` is already named and accessible from the code behind, you can directly use it.
If you are in another control, you can either expose it through a property or perform a recursive search going from child to child.